# MongoDB only three of four shards being used

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding

Using MongoDB 2.6, I've setup four replication sets: a, b, c & d:

**>rs.conf()**

```
a:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "name_of_replset",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "fedora_cje:port_number"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "fedora_cje:port_number"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "fedora_cje:port_number"
        }
    ]
}
```

Those replication sets have been added to shards

**>sh.status()**

```
 shards:
    {  "_id" : "a",  "host" : "a/fedora_cje:27000,fedora_cje:27001,fedora_cje:27002" }
    {  "_id" : "b",  "host" : "b/fedora_cje:27100,fedora_cje:27101,fedora_cje:27102" }
    {  "_id" : "c",  "host" : "c/fedora_cje:27200,fedora_cje:27201,fedora_cje:27202" }
    {  "_id" : "d",  "host" : "d/fedora_cje:27300,fedora_cje:27301,fedora_cje:27302" }
```

At the bottom of sh.status(), I am seeing this message

```
{  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "d" }
{  "_id" : "test_collection",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "d" }
```

but test and test_collection don't exist in the test_cluster database.

Inserting records, the fourth replication set and fourth shard are apparently ignored.

test_cluster.test_cluster_collection.stats()

```
"nchunks" : 3,
"shards" : {
    "a" : {...
    "b" : {...
    "c" : {
```

Notice also that the number of chunks remains at 3.

I am using the default /etc/mongod.conf file.

This is the insert statement being used:

```
>use test_cluster
>t=db.test_cluster.test_sharded_collection
>for( var i=0; i < 20000; i++ ){t.insert( { x:i,y:3,z:"test                       test" } )}
```

**Question**: Why is the fourth replication set and consequently the fourth shard being ignored during inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few confusing pieces here, first you list this piece of `sh.status()`:

```
{  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "d" }
{  "_id" : "test_collection",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "d" }
```

That means that there is a test **database**, a test_collection **database**, not collections.  It also indicates that neither of them are sharded - that is what `"partitioned" : false` means.

You then show some output from `test_cluster.test_cluster_collection.stats()` but that is not one of the databases from the `sh.status` command.  It is a collection from the `test_cluster` database, and there is no indication of how that is sharded, though it would be listed in `sh.status()`.  Basically the two pieces of information have nothing to do with each other.

Your `for` loop will also be inserting into the test_sharded_collection as a sub-collection of `test_cluster`.  In other words, the full namespace you are inserting into is `test_cluster.test_cluster.test_sharded_collection`, and I suspect that is not sharded which is why you are likely not seeing the chunks increase.  What I suspect you intended to do was insert into `test_cluster.test_sharded_collection`.  Try this for your inserts instead:

```
use test_cluster;
for( var i=0; i < 20000; i++ ){db.test_sharded_collection.insert( { x:i,y:3,z:"test                       test" } )};
```

The full output of `sh.status()`, and specifically the section about the `test_sharded_collection` would help me confirm my suspicions.

Comment: Hello Adam, I will get back to you shortly on this. I cleared out the cluster directory for the MongoDB chapter 6 homework and need to start over.

Comment: Hello Adam, working on 202 now and got a chance to redo the cluster and replications sets. Stopping the balancer before inserts did the trick.